# Spring Integration Cassandra persistence workflow

Tags: cassandra, spring-integration, spring-data-cassandra

I try to realize the following workflow with Spring Integration:

- 1) Poll REST API
- 2) store the POJO in Cassandra cluster

It's my first try with Spring Integration, so I'm still a bit overwhelmed about the mass of information from the reference. After some research, I could make the following work.

- 1) Poll REST API
- 2) Transform mapped POJO JSON result into a string
- 3) save string into file

Here's the code:

```
@Configuration
public class ConsulIntegrationConfig {

    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "consulHttp", poller = @Poller(maxMessagesPerPoll = "1", fixedDelay = "1000"))
    public String consulAgentPoller() {
        return "";
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel consulHttp() {
        return MessageChannels.direct("consulHttp").get();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "consulHttp")
    MessageHandler consulAgentHandler() {
        final HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler =
            new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("http://localhost:8500/v1/agent/self");
        handler.setExpectedResponseType(AgentSelfResult.class);
        handler.setOutputChannelName("consulAgentSelfChannel");
        LOG.info("Created bean'consulAgentHandler'");
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel consulAgentSelfChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct("consulAgentSelfChannel").get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel consulAgentSelfFileChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct("consulAgentSelfFileChannel").get();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "consulAgentSelfFileChannel")
    MessageHandler consulAgentFileHandler() {
        final Expression directoryExpression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("'./'");
        final FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(directoryExpression);
        handler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> "../../agent_self.txt");
        handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND);
        handler.setCharset("UTF-8");
        handler.setExpectReply(false);
        return handler;
     }
}

@Component
public final class ConsulAgentTransformer {

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "consulAgentSelfChannel", outputChannel = "consulAgentSelfFileChannel")
    public String transform(final AgentSelfResult json) throws IOException {
        final String result = new StringBuilder(json.toString()).append("\n").toString();
        return result;
}
```

This works fine!

But now, instead of writing the object to a file, I want to store it in a Cassandra cluster with spring-data-cassandra. For that, I commented out the file handler in the config file, return the POJO in transformer and  created the following, :

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "consulCassandraGateway", defaultRequestChannel = "consulAgentSelfFileChannel")
public interface CassandraStorageService {

    @Gateway(requestChannel="consulAgentSelfFileChannel")
    void store(AgentSelfResult agentSelfResult);
}

@Component
public final class CassandraStorageServiceImpl implements CassandraStorageService {

    @Override
    public void store(AgentSelfResult agentSelfResult) {
        //use spring-data-cassandra repository to store
        LOG.info("Received 'AgentSelfResult': {} in Cassandra cluster...");
        LOG.info("Trying to store 'AgentSelfResult' in Cassandra cluster...");
}
}
```

But this seems to be a wrong approach, the service method is never triggered.

So my question is, what would be a correct approach for my usecase? Do I have to implement the MessageHandler interface in my service component, and use a @ServiceActivator in my config. Or is there something missing in my current "gateway-approach"?? Or maybe there is another solution, that I'm not able to see..

Like mentioned before, I'm new to SI, so this may be a stupid question...

Nevertheless, thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you are wiring in your `CassandraStorageService` bean.

The [Spring Integration Cassandra Extension Project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-cassandra) has a message-handler implementation.

The [Cassandra Sink in spring-cloud-stream-modules](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-modules/tree/master/cassandra-sink) uses it with Java configuration so you can use that as an example.

Comment: Yes, I know. I think I didn't understand the gateway yet. Another idea was to wire the service into the transformer, but that that doesn't seem clean to me. The links look promising, I'll check them tommorow. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally made it work. All I needed to do was

```
@Component
public final class CassandraStorageServiceImpl implements CassandraStorageService {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="consulAgentSelfFileChannel")
    @Override
    public void store(AgentSelfResult agentSelfResult) {
        //use spring-data-cassandra repository to store
        LOG.info("Received 'AgentSelfResult': {}...");
        LOG.info("Trying to store 'AgentSelfResult' in Cassandra cluster...");
    }
}
```

The CassandraMessageHandler and the spring-cloud-streaming seemed to be a to big overhead to my use case, and I didn't really understand yet... And with this solution, I keep control over what happens in my spring component.